# FTP deployed Umbraco site locally?

Tags: umbraco, webmatrix, webdeploy

Greets!

I have an Umbraco site on a server which only allows FTP access (for now).
Like any sane developer on a big project, I need to be able to split the development into a local development and remote deployment branches. Is there a simple solution that would allow me to do so without installing something like WebDeploy server-side?
To clarify - I need to be able to...

1. Pull
2. Develop
3. Run locally to see results
4. Push
5. Repeat

...over FTP.

P.S. I have already contacted the server provider to find out if i have any other access options besides FTP, however, it would still be beneficial to know of a solution over FTP.

Comment: Maybe umbraco courier will do /some/ of what you want (sync data, document types, etc?) but it runs over HTTP and I don't believe it will push your binary files etc

Comment: Well it seems that in my scenario (as far as I can tell) the simplest solution was to create a folder substructure, with identical files for development/testing purposes. This, however, does not protect from shoddy package installs, and still requires me to manually copy/paste all of the code/configurations to ensure the "makeshift dev branch" is identical to the production/deployment branch. So now i can develop on "fakedomain.com/test/page" and copy to "fakedomain.com/page" when I am satisfied with the solution. Does this merit an answer?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is quite late but maybe still helpful.
I think what you are looking for is an automated solution if I am not mistaken.

My setup here is quite similar as if I am coding something and need to upload it right away for backup/review/sharing purposes, I created a script which is monitoring my "Output" Folder and as soon as something changes, uploads everything to a remote site. (Or locally if that is needed)

I am using SysaxAutomation (sysax.com) which can create triggered/automated tasks and upload/download/mirror locally and/or remote files.